# Map from Typed object to dynamic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, mapping, automapper

I was trying to map from a typed object to `dynamic` but that seems to be not possible.

For example:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerName {get; set;}
    public Category Category {get; set;} 
}

public class Category
{
    public string CategoryName {get; set;}
    public int IgnoreProp {get; set;}
}
```

Then I would like my result like below:

```
var customer = new Customer
         { 
             CustomerName = "Ibrahim", 
             Category = new Category
                 { 
                   CategoryName = "Human", 
                   IgnoreProp = 10 
                 } 
         };

dynamic dynamicCustomer = Mapper.Map<Customer, dynamic>(customer);
```

Can I configure `AutoMapper` to somehow handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is possible, the following test succeeds:

```
public class SourceObject
{
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }
    public SourceObject SourceProperty { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<dynamic>(new SourceObject() {IntProperty = 123, StringProperty = "abc", SourceProperty = new SourceObject()});
        Console.WriteLine("Int " + result.IntProperty);
        Console.WriteLine("String " + result.StringProperty);
        Console.WriteLine("Object is " + (result.SourceProperty == null ? "null" : "not null").ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This outputs a dynamic object with the mapped properties from the SourceObject

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use AutoMapper to map to a dynamic object:

```
dynamic dynamicCustomer = customer;
Console.WriteLine(dynamicCustomer.CustomerName); // "Ibrahim"
Console.WriteLine(dynamicCustomer.Category.CategoryName); // "Human"
```